# RUN puppeteer in a Node Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer

I have a Node JS Backend, which should use puppeteer for screenshoting my pdfs.
On my local System (MAC OS) everything works fine.
Now I want to publish this as a docker container in an Azure App Service.
The app starts well, but when I trigger puppeteer, the following error occurs:

> Error: Could not find Chromium (rev. 1069273). This can occur if
> either
>
> 1. you did not perform an
>    installation before running the script (e.g. `npm install`) or
> 2. your cache path is incorrectly
>    configured (which is: /root/.cache/puppeteer).
>    For (2), check out our guide on
>    configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:slim

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

# INSTALL PUPPETEER DEPENDENCIES
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gnupg wget chromium -y && \
  wget --quiet --output-document=- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-archive.gpg && \
  sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y --no-install-recommends && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./backend/ .

RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The code of the route:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
...
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
})
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "puppeteer": "^19.4.1",
}
```

I followed this guide for my code: https://dev.to/cloudx/how-to-use-puppeteer-inside-a-docker-container-568c

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can take off everything about puppeteer from the Dockerfile and simply add a puppeteer.config.cjs file.

```
const {join} = require('path');

/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
  // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
  cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer'),
};
```

Sadly, this installs puppeteer in the /root directory. If you want to move it to another directory, add

```
RUN mv /root/.cache /alternate-directory
```

to your code